# How to stop the async class in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have two buttons in my UI.Both button actions i am calling the same async class.when i click on the second button,first button execution of the async thread stops forcebly and start the execution again.

How to stop forceble execution of async thread in android?

Answer (score 0):

To cancel an `async task`, you may need to call the `cancel()` method on the task object, with parameter true.

Eg:

`yourAsynObj.cancel(true);`

also, you need to check if the task is cancelled in your `doInBackground` method, you can check it as

```
if(!yourAsynObj.isCancelled){
    // do things
} else {
    // Cancel doing things
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private YourAsyncTask mTask;
```

declare your asyncTask in your activity.

```
mTask = new YourAsyncTask().execute();
```

instantiate it like this.

```
mTask.cancel(true);
```

kill/cancel it like this.